# Does "Thanks to" in the sentence express "Thanks"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

"Okey! Thanks to Danny giving us a brief overview of the production line. It seems it is the most profitable line. " Here, is "Thanks to Danny" the meaning of "Thank Danny"? or just means "Due to"?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for giving these comments. I have also another question. In the original sentence, "It looks like it will be our frofitable line yet." here, is "yet" used here the meaning of "up to now"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, the speaker is using *thanks to* to express gratitude to Danny. This usage is often preceded by a pronoun:

> (Let's give) our thanks to Danny for giving us a brief overview of the production line.

*Thanks to* can also have the meaning (as you suggested) of "due to/because of." When it is used with this meaning, the expression may have either a sarcastic/negative or sincere/positive connotation that is usually evident from the **context** of the statement. For example:

> Thanks to my little brother, my phone is broken.

This sentence indicates that the speaker's little brother broke the phone and the speaker blames him for it. *Thanks to* has a sarcastic/negative connotation.

> Thanks to my fitness coach, I am now much stronger and healthier.

This sentence indicates that the speaker's fitness coach was responsible for his improvement. *Thanks to* has a sincere/positive connotation.

Answer (score 4):

When you say (with a bit of correction):

> *Okay*! **Thanks to Danny** *for* giving us a brief overview of the production line. It seems it is the most profitable line.

Here you are thanking him.

But if you said something like:

> **Thanks to Danny**, everyone will need to work overtime to fix his mistake.

it means "due to Danny". Using "thanks" is a bit facetious as used here.